# Objective-c disable function with conditional macros

Tags: objective-c, macros

I have a custom logging function that i would like to disable for realease builds. But the problem is it only lets me to replace that function with another empty one. Here's what i would like to do:

```
#ifdef SMTH
    #define logfunction(...)
#else
    void logfunction(NSString *fmt, ...) { some logging code goes here }
#endif
```

To make this work, i could replace the function with a macro, including VA_ARGS and such, but ... the problem is that my xCode loses code completion inside the braces of logfunction(). Now if the logging facility is defined as a function - code completion works fine.

The only solution i have so far is this:

```
#ifdef SMTH
    void logfunction(NSString *fmt, ...) { /* no code here */ }
#else
    void logfunction(NSString *fmt, ...) { some logging code goes here }
#endif
```

This works fine, but there is a call to an empty function in release builds. Is there any way to work around this?

**UPDATE - my bad - everything works**

The first example actually works, i simply forgot to do the same conditional macro in the ".h" file ...

Comment: compiler is smart enough to remove empty function calls.

Comment: I don't think all compilers do that. I can't find any official info, stating that any of the apple compilers optimize out empty calls. Are you sure about this?

Comment: There was a bug filed for llvm that it contains function prelude and ret asm statements. Here's a link with confirmation of fixing it (note the date): http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmbugs/2009-January/006704.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that your current solution is already good enough. The empty function wont cause much trouble (in terms of wasting much time when it is called). Probably the compiler will even remove the call to the empty function altogether.

However, if you still want to get rid of it, you can try what I am doing:
Wrap your log function into a macro, and define that macro conditionally.

Example:

```
#ifdef SMTH
    #define logfunction(fmt, ...) 
#else
    #define logfunction(fmt, ...) __logfunction((fmt), ##__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

where `__logfunction(NSString *fmt, ...)` is your actual logging function. This will completely remove the call to the function, when your `SMTH` is set.

By the way, you may want to use the `DEBUG` flag, that is set per default in XCode for non-release builds (see the "Preprocessor Macros" setting in your target in XCode). You would need to switch the cases around inside the `#ifdef`, obviously, or make it a `#ifndef DEBUG`.

Comment: That was actually the way i used to do things prior to my current solution. But, like i said in my original post, xcode loses code completion when i type logfunction(... anywhere. Anything inside the braces cannot code-complete... and that is an irritating inconvenience. It only auto-completes inside of a real function, but not a macro for some reason.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not autocompleting"? For me, it autocompletes fine like this.

Comment: Well, if i, for instance, try to type "logfunction([NSString" - i won't get NSString's completions. The function arguments themselves autocomplete just fine. If that works for you, you might have a different version of xcode. Anyway, problem is already solved - thank you for your help.

Comment: It worked under XCode 4 and is still working under XCode 5. Would you mind sharing your new solution?

Comment: It was never an issue in the first places as it turns out. I simply had forgotten that i had conflicting definitions in my outdated ".h" file. The first code sample in my original post actually works.